# CalenderView does not exist - trying to implement DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar, date-format

I'm trying to implement a DatePickerDialog that pops up when a user clicks on a text box. Once the date is set, i'm trying to set the textbox's text to a formatted version of the date -sounds simple, yes?

I'm getting an error telling me that calender view of the DatePicker object passed into the onDateSet event handler for the DatePickerDialog does not exist!! Why would this be? I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: I'm targetting API 23, min API 19, running this on API 22

Here's the code for my OnClickListener of my EditText...

```
private class DateClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    int mYear;
    int mMonth;
    int mDay;

    public void formatDate(long selectedDate){
        mDateText.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(selectedDate));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //To show current date in the datepicker
        Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(CreateOuttingActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                formatDate(datepicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
            }
        },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
        mDatePicker.show();
    }
}
```

Here's the exact error trace:

```
03-10 17:52:20.750 21766-21766/... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: ..., PID: 21766
                                                               java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker
                                                                   at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.getCalendarView(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:498)
                                                                   at android.widget.DatePicker.getCalendarView(DatePicker.java:377)
                                                                   at ...CreateActivity$DateClickListener$1.onDateSet(CreateActivity.java:70)
                                                                   at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCalendarView()` is not supported in post API 21.
You can try this -

```
 DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(CreateOuttingActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                formatDate(getTimeFromDatePicker(view));
            }
        },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

where getTimeFromDatePicker() can be defined like -

```
public long getTimeFromDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Was not aware it wasn't supported anymore.